# Compiler error with C++17 static inline members

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static, inline, c++17

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, and from what I've seen it does support C++17 static inline class variables. My issue is that if I leave all members unitialised it works fine but I get a compiler error when initialising certain members. In the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    static inline int a;
    static inline int b;
    static inline int c;
};


int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    std::cout << foo.a; // Prints 0

    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine.

In the following cases I get the compiler error:

```
class Foo
{public:
    static inline int a = 7; // Initialise
    static inline int b;
    static inline int c;
}; //ErrorC1001 An internal error has occurred in the compiler. 

class Foo
{public:
    static inline int a = 7; // Initialise
    static inline int b = 7; // Initialise
    static inline int c;
}; //ErrorC1001 An internal error has occurred in the compiler. 

class Foo
{public:
    static inline int a = 7; // Initialise
    static inline int b = 7; // Initialise
    static inline int c = 7; // Initialise
}; // Initialise all three, no error. Works fine.
```

However this works:

```
class Foo
{public:
    static inline int a;
    static inline int b = 7; // Initialise second
    static inline int c;
}; // Does compile but doesn't initialise 'b' to 7, instead it is 0
```

So I think that initialising the first member requires you initialise every single other member, however this is only the case if you initialise the very first member. It took me ages to figure out why it was giving this message, is this a bug? Or is there a strange requirement to initialise all `static` `inline` members only if you initialise the first one?

Also, I've tried using the `static` `inline` member at onlinegdb.com, compiling in C++17, and it seems as though it doesn't support it, as the error message is:

> error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static
>   member 'Foo::a'

See [Online GDB](https://onlinegdb.com/BJl7CCz7X)

Comment: "*An internal error has occurred in the compiler*" Anytime you see something like that, this means the compiler has crashed. Even if your code is ill-formed, it's still a compiler bug for it to *crash*.

Answer (score 3):

> is this a bug?

This is certainly a [bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/223554/compiler-crashing.html) in MSVC.

As per [class.static.data/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#class.static.data-3):

> An `inline` `static` *data member* may be defined in the class definition
>   and may specify a [*brace-or-equal-initializer*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#nt:brace-or-equal-initializer).

Thus, it is acceptable to have [*default member initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) for *non-const* static inline class member variables.

It works fine using [GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PNct6PPtBN1SW27d) and [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kKPnX1MjIXRKjRKm).

Comment: When you say it works fine in GCC and Clang, would the fact that it doesn't work at onlinegdb in the link in my answer mean that the compiler they use isn't GCC or Clang?

Comment: I have the exact same problem as the OP, except mine doesn't work even initializing all members of the class. In fact my class has only one member and it gives me the error `error: 'xxx' declared as an 'inline' field` and `error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'yyy::xxx'`. So the problem is the compiler? I have GCC 6.3. What should I do then? (I'm using VSCode btw)

Comment: NVM, I've just updated my GCC through MinGW manager from 6.3 to 8.2 and it works fine.