# Static variable from a class (c++)

Tags: c++, qt

I`m trying to create a class and inside it define static variables to use them in anywhere without creating an object from that and access variables from that object like this:

```
ConfigClass::serverHost+"/server.php";
```

for this i wrote this code in header of that class:

```
static inline QString serverHosts="http://server.com";
```

whene i build my project with gcc on linux there is no problem
but whene i build that with msvc(visual studio 2017 msvc v141) on windows not supported ([bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276050/compiler-error-with-c17-static-inline-members))

**what is the best way to define static variables and use them anywhere ??**

i know **extern** but What's the better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it inside the class file after the declaration:

```
class A{ 
public:
    static QString serverHosts;
};
Qstring A::serverHosts('http://server.com');
```

Note: is recommend defining it in the `.h`, but rather the `.cpp` if possible

Comment: Note I wouldn't recommend defining it in the .h, but rather the .cpp. Minor nit-pick, but you didn't specify so I thought I'd just mention it.

Comment: @Chipster yes absolutely, but in case for example of template, you can't, however i'll add it to the answer