# Is it possible to initialise a static member in a static method of a class in C++?

Tags: c++, initialization, declaration, static-methods, static-members

So I have the static member `precision` and a public static method to set its value in my class (the code below is stripped down a lot).

```cpp
class Foo {
private:
    typedef unsigned short precision_t;
    static precision_t precision;
public:
    static void set_precision(precision_t value) {
        precision_t precision = value;
        /* other stuff */
    }
    
    static precision_t get_precision() {
        return precision;
    }
};
```

When I create an instance and then set the value, it seems to work fine, but trying to get the value gives a slightly cryptic error: `` main.cpp:(.text._ZN3Foo13get_precisionEv[_ZN3Foo13get_precisionEv]+0x7): undefined reference to `Foo::precision' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status `` (run on onlinegdb.com).

Exact code in main:

```cpp
Foo *foo = new Foo(); //fine
foo->set_precision(5); //no error, but probably wrong given undefined reference
std::cout << Foo::get_precision(); //shows above error
```

My original code for `set_precision` looked more like

```cpp
static void set_precision(precision_t value) {
    static bool defined = false;
    if (defined) {
        precision = value
    } else {
        precision_t precision = value;
        defined = true;
    }
    /* other stuff */
}
```

so it would initialise `precision` the first time only.

I also attempted to do this for the vector which stores pointers to all of the instances instead of having to write the code to initialise outside of the class/in the `.cpp` file.

Is it even possible to do this or do I have to initialise (the vector storing the instance pointers and the unsigned short storing the current precision) in the `.cpp` file before the `main` function?

Comment: All `static` members [should be defined](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#link-errs-static-data-mems) exactly once in the program. You can think of it as a "where to allocate static memory for this object"-ish instruction for the compiler. Or just use `static inline`

Comment: Also, `precision_t precision = value;` in `set_precision` sets a _local_ variable, not the static member variable of the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo {
private:
    typedef unsigned short precision_t;
    static inline precision_t precision; 
    //static precision_t precision; //when not using static inline
public:
    static void set_precision(precision_t value) {
        //precision_t precision = value; //<<-- error in your code
        precision = value; 
        /* other stuff */
    }
    
    static precision_t get_precision() {
        return precision;
    }
};

//Foo::precision_t Foo::precision = 0; //when not using static inline

int main() {
    Foo *foo = new Foo(); //fine
    foo->set_precision(5); //no error, but probably wrong given undefined reference
    std::cout << Foo::get_precision(); //shows above error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I previously tried this myself and it didn't work.If anyone finds that this code has an error about `inline`, it seems you have to use C++17 or above. (This is not the default for the latest version of GCC; try -std=c++17). There is apparently a bug in MSVC relating to it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276050/compiler-error-with-c17-static-inline-members).